# Accessing outer class hidden base property from nested class

Tags: c#, inheritance, nested-class

Let's say I have a class which has a property hiding it's base property and a nested class inside this class. Is it possible to access the base **hidden** **virtual** property from the nested class?

Here is an example:

```
class BaseClass
{
    protected virtual String SomeProperty {get; set;}
}

class Inherited : BaseClass
{
    protected new String SomeProperty {get; set;}

    class Nested
    {
        Inherited parent;
        public Nested(Inherited parent)
        {
            this.parent = parent;
        }

        public void SomeMethod()
        {
            //How do I access the SomeProperty which belongs to the BaseClass? 
        }
    }
}
```

The only solution that I can think of is to add a private method to Inherited class which returns `base.SomeProperty` Is there a better solution?

Comment: Where are you trying to access it from, and why have you hidden the property in the first place?

Comment: I'm trying to access it from the method of the nested class. I have hidden the base property because the new property provides more features than the base property and I do not want to have two properties.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could cast your `InheritedClass` reference to `BaseClass`. Since you hide the base property instead of overriding it, this should do the trick.

```
public void SomeMethod()
{
    BaseClass baseRef = parent;
    // do stuff with the base property:
    baseRef.SomeProperty = someValue;
}
```

**Edit:**

To make this work, the `SomeProperty` property of the `BaseClass` has to be accessible to the nested class, either by making it `internal` (if you don't want to make the property accessible outside the declaring assembly) or `protected internal` (if you want to allow overriding in derived classes from other assemblies).

If both options are off limits (ie. when your derived class already is in another assembly), you won't get around declaring a wrapper property.

```
private string SomeBaseProperty
{
    get
    {
        return base.SomeProperty;
    }

    set
    {
        base.SomeProperty = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I forgot that the property is indeed virtual. I have updated my question.

Comment: As long as you still use shadowing, my solution will work anyway ;)

Comment: This is causing Compiler Error CS1540: Cannot access protected member 'member' via a qualifier of type 'type1'; the qualifier must be of type 'type2' (or derived from it) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9zta243.aspx

Comment: why is the property `protected` anyway? Can't you just make it `internal` or `protected internal`?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't modify base class source code as it is a framework dll.

Comment: I have already updated my answer to reflect that possibility ;)