# get hidden derived property from base class

Tags: c#, overriding, hidden

The **classA** has property pA which has type of baseType.

I have created **classB** derived from **classA** and it is *hiding* pA property with *"new"* modifier: newType pA;

newType derived from baseType...

How can I refer to the classB pA in baseType:
In classA the instance of classB has null value of pA, but in classB pA has the initiated value.

I would like to call a classA base method using the value of classB's pA!

*override* is working, but for that I have to use baseType:
public override baseType pA;

using "*new*" is better then I can use newType:
public new newType pA;

Or I can do declaration + override:

```
public newType pB { get; set; }
public override baseType pA { get => pB; }
```

Above is working, but better would be to use "new" and in the base type pA should get the value from the descendant classB:

```
public virtual baseType pA {
get { return GetType().GetProperties().Where(t => t.Name == "pA" && !(t.DeclaringType is classA)).First().GetValue(this) as baseType... }
set {...} }
```

The better solution also working, but checking the DeclaringType has an issue:
GetType().GetProperties().Where(t => t.Name == "pA") will return with 2 properties and only one is for classB's pA property.

Similar issue:
[Accessing outer class hidden...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8925749/accessing-outer-class-hidden-base-property-from-nested-class)

The referenced article is not solution to my problem.
Cannot use *((classB)this).pA* in classA.
Don't want to create that dependency.
When I am creating *classC* inherited from *classA* then it will not work...

I have already sorted out the *DeclaringType* issue:

In classA I have defined pA like this:

```
public virtual baseType pA {
        get {
            var p = GetType().GetProperties().Where(t => t.Name == "pA" && !(t.DeclaringType.Equals(typeof(classA))));
            if (p.Count() > 0) return p.First().GetValue(this) as baseType; else return _pA;
        }
            set => _pA = value;
    }
```

So I can overwrite the pA property with new type In classB:

```
public new newType pA { get; set; }
```

Then classA's hidden pA property will be replaced with classB's property.
When callin the **baseMethod(pA) in classA** the pA's value will be the **value from classB**.
classA pA type is baseType
classB pA type is newType...

Comment: It is very unclear why the question you linked to is not answering your question (and hence I closed it as duplicate for now). Please [edit] your question to explain why `((ClassB)this).pA` does not work in your `ClassA`. (Note that what you are asking sound ... not an ideal design. It is a generally agreed upon that shadowing causes troubles all around outside very narrow use case it is designed for. Another note: please clarify how "cs.net" mentioned in the title relates to C# - if you just trying  to advertise some random web site it's considered spam)